# Restrict Jenkins Slave node based on time-of-day

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a farm which is busy through the day building for developers, but is idle in the overnight hours.

I have a second farm which is busy through the night, but rarely through the day.

Is there a way to assign a job to a node not only by label, but also by time of day?

So if I have build_node and regression_node label.  I could trigger a job which would run on nodes where the `node label is ((build_node if between 9pm-5am) or regression_node)`?

Thanks.

Comment: You can move the nodes to online/offline depending on time.(programmatically).  is that an option

Comment: @Jayan Appreciate the comment.  I'd like the nodes to remain online, but to purpose them out based on time of day.  E.G. During work hours, 80% of nodes should be for dev jobs while after hours, 80% should be for regression runs.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can create a jenkins job that will assign the jobs to the needed nodes and schedule this job to run per you needs.

For example a job with the following groovy script defined as `Execute system Groovy script` will assign all jobs with a pattern `regression node` in their job description to the label `regression-node`

```
import hudson.model.*

jobs=Hudson.instance.getItems()
for (job in jobs){

    description = job.getDescription()
    if (description =~ /regression-node/){
        println ("Assigning $job to the restriction-node")
        label= Hudson.instance.getLabel('regression-node')
        job.setAssignedLabel(label)
    }

}
```